# How to find and drop a student with nodes

Tags: c, struct, nodes, doubly-linked-list

Im having trouble trying to figure out what to do as far as dropping my students using the nodes that they are tied too because for some reason i cannot remove a node from the middle of my list. I havent been able to figure it out. Any ideas would be gladly appreciated. This is what I was thinking would work but it did'nt

```
   Void drop_student ( double_linkedlist_t* listPtr)
   {
    Node_t* CurPtr;
    Node_t* nodePtr;
    CurPtr = listPtr->headPtr;
     While ( nodePtr != CurPtr )
     {
        If ( nodePtr == CurPtr ) 
         {
            //found it at beginning
            CurPtr = listPtr->headPtr->nextPtr
          }
      }
   }
```

Or something of that nature. I just need to input a students id and then it should find which node its tied too and delete it from my list. Thank you for help!

Comment: What is this ?? What is the problem ?? Code segment is incomplete also !!! What is this ???!!??

Comment: @SurajeetBharati well first of all i do realize it is very incomplete it is a partial idea on what i need to do with what i have posted in my paragraph. its not a full code.

Comment: so, you are trying to delete node with address `nodePtr` from linked list namely `listPtr`. Is it so ?

Comment: @SurajeetBharati yes

Comment: This is your homework, I think. Do it yourself. Google it for tutorial and learn yourself.

Comment: @SurajeetBharati i literally just said i need an idea not for you to do it for me, and i have used google to search for examples that can relate what im needing to do. And dont come into a post and just assume something be helpful or dont post at all. Like maybe saying you could probably try this link or try this blah be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to understand it. Reply if you face any problem.

I am assuming the node exists in the linked list.

```
void drop_student ( double_linkedlist_t* listPtr){
    Node_t* CurPtr;
    Node_t* nodePtr;
    CurPtr = listPtr->headPtr;

    if ( nodePtr == CurPtr ) {
        //found it at beginning
        listPtr->headPtr = listPtr->headPtr->nextPtr;
        return;
    }

    //if not at begining search for the node through iteration
    While ( nodePtr != CurPtr->nextPtr ){
        CurPtr = CurPtr->nextPtr;
    }

    //if it is end node
    if(nodePtr -> next = NULL){
        CurPtr->nextPtr=NULL;
        return;
    }

    //if in middle
    nodePtr -> nextPtr -> previousPtr = curPtr;
    curPtr -> nextPtr = nodePtr -> nextPtr;

}
```

Follow the figures in [this link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/delete-a-node-in-a-doubly-linked-list/) for better understanding.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I better understand what im needing to do and how it all works.